# Local ring homomorphism induced by $\varphi$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

At page $59$ in Görtz & Wedhorn 's "Algebraic Geometry 1" book, there is the following text:

> "Let $\varphi : A \rightarrow B$ be a homomorphism of rings and set $X = \operatorname{Spec} B$ and $Y = \operatorname{Spec} A$. Let $^a\varphi : \operatorname{Spec} B \rightarrow \operatorname{Spec} A$ be the associated continuous map. We will now define a morphism $(f,f^b):X \rightarrow Y$ of locally ringed space and such that $f = ^a\varphi$ and $f^b_Y:A=\mathscr O_Y(Y) \rightarrow (f_*\mathscr O_X(Y))=B$ equals $\varphi$.
>
> Set $f = ^a\varphi$, for $s \in A$, We have $f^{-1}(D(s))=A_s \rightarrow B_{\varphi(s)}= (f_*\mathscr O_X)(D(s))$ is the homomorphism induced by $\varphi$. This ring homomorphism is compatible with restrictions to principal open subsets $D(t) \subset D(s)$. As the principal open subsets form a basis of the topology, this defines a homomorphism $f^b:\mathscr O_Y \rightarrow f_*\mathscr O_X$ of sheaves of rings.
>
> For $x \in X$, **the homomorphism $f^\#_x: \mathscr O_{Y,f(x)} = A_{\varphi^{-1}(p_x)} \rightarrow B_{p_x} = \mathscr O_{X,x}$ is the homomorphism induced by $\varphi$** and in particular it is a local ring homomorphism. This finishes the definition of $(f,f^b)$."

I understand the first two paragraphs. So we have a special homomorphism $(f,f^b)$ of locally ringed spaces $(X,\mathscr O_X)$ and $(Y,\mathscr O_Y)$. This $(f,f^b)$ is special enough such that for $s \in A$, $f^b_{D(s)}:f^{-1}(D(s))=A_s \rightarrow B_{\varphi(s)}= (f_*\mathscr O_X)(D(s))$ is the homomorphism induced by $\varphi$, that is $f^b_{D(s)}(\frac {a} {s^n}) = \frac {\varphi(a)} {\varphi(s)^n}$, and $f=a^\varphi$. Now we can say that $(f,f^b)$ is fixed because for $s\in A$,$D(s)$ is the principal open subsets so that $f^b$ is fixed. And $f^b$ is fixed so is $f^\#$ since $f^b$ and $f^\#$ have an one-to-one correspondence.

Now we have $f^\#$ being fixed, so for $x\in X$, the local ring homomorphism defined as $f^\#_x$ is fixed.

Then I have trouble understanding the third paragraph which says "For $x \in X$, the homomorphism $f^\#_x: \mathscr O_{Y,f(x)} = A_{\varphi^{-1}(p_x)} \rightarrow B_{p_x} = \mathscr O_{X,x}$ is the homomorphism induced by $\varphi$".

That means $f^\#_x(\frac {a} {q^n}) = \frac {\varphi(a)} {\varphi(q)^n}$.

But it is not at all obvious, right? So why is $f^\#_x$ being the homomorphism such that $f^\#_x(\frac {a} {q^n}) = \frac {\varphi(a)} {\varphi(q)^n}$?

Comment: Do you mean Görtz & Wedhorn, or are you just on very familiar terms with the authors? (Ulrich & Torsten are their first names.)

Comment: @HansLundmark Oh sorry, I thought that people are being called by their first names... Thanks for that. I will correct it.

Comment: Maybe (or maybe not) if you talk to them in person, but when you refer to authors of textbooks, you always use the family name (or the full name), so that people will know which book you are talking about.

Comment: @HansLundmark Get it, thanks. I will pay attention to that.

Comment: Please use `$\operatorname{Spec}$` to format $\operatorname{Spec}$, as it produces better formatting. I've made the changes for you this time.

Comment: @KReiser Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Consider an arbitrary but fixed element $x\in A_{\varphi^{-1}({\mathfrak q})}$: It is then of the form $\tfrac{a}{b}$ for $b\in\varphi^{-1}(B\setminus{\mathfrak q})$, hence can also be viewed as the image of the 'same' element $\tfrac{a}{b}$ interpreted as an element of $A_b$, under the canonical homomorphism $A_b\to A_{\varphi^{-1}({\mathfrak q})}$. Next, by naturality, the composition $A_b\to A_{\varphi^{-1}({\mathfrak q})}\to B_{\mathfrak q}$ is the same as the composition $A_b\to B_{\varphi(b)}\to B_{\mathfrak q}$. Finally, you have already identified $A_b\to B_{\varphi(b)}$ in the latter composition as being the canonical map. Can you fill in the details here?

Comment: Suppose for any $p_x \in \operatorname{Spec} B$, and $q_x =f(p_x)$(or equivalently $=\varphi^{-1}(p_x)$) $\in \operatorname{Spec} A $ , the local ring homomorphism at point $p_x$ is $f^\#_x : A_{q_x} \rightarrow B_{p_x}$.

I wonder what is the canonical homomorphism of $f^\#_x$?

Comment: I got another expression for $f^\#_x$. Along the path $\mathscr O_Y \rightarrow f_*O_X \rightarrow \mathscr O_X$, take the "direct limit" operation, we get $f_{\operatorname{push},q_x}: A_{q_x}=\mathscr O_{Y,q_x} \rightarrow f_*O_{X,q_x} = B_{\varphi(q_x^c)}$ with $f_{\operatorname{push},q_x}(\frac {a} {s^n})= \frac {\varphi(a)} {\varphi(s)^n}$. ($B_{\varphi(q_x^c)}$ means $B$ localize at multiplicatively closed set $\varphi(q_x^c)$).

Comment: And also $\operatorname{Res} : B_{\varphi(q_x^c)} \rightarrow B_{p_x}$. Here $\operatorname{Res}$ is defined strangely. For $s \notin q_x$, $\exists t \notin p_x$ such that $D(t) \subset D(\varphi(s))$, which means it exists $r \in \mathbb{N}$ and $b_s \in B$ such that $t^r = b_s\varphi(s)$. So for any $\frac {b} {\varphi(s)^n} \in B_{\varphi(q_x^c)}$, define $\operatorname{Res}(\frac {b} {\varphi(s)^n}) = \frac {b b_s^n} {t^{rn}} \in B_{p_x}$.

Comment: Now Compose these $2$ homomorphism $f_{\operatorname{push},q_x}$ and $\operatorname{Res}$, we get the local homomorphism that we want. That is $f^\#_x = \operatorname{Res} \circ f_{\operatorname{push},q_x}$ and $\operatorname{Res} \circ f_{\operatorname{push},q_x}(\frac {a} {s^n})=\operatorname{Res}(\frac {\varphi(a)} {\varphi(s)^n}) = \frac {\varphi(a) b_s^n} {t^{rn}}$. How can I get rid of the ugly $r$ and $b_s$?

Comment: Now I know why. Because $t^r= b_s\varphi(s)$, then $\frac {\varphi(a)b^n_s}{t^{rn}} = \frac {\varphi(a)b^n_s}{b_s^n\varphi(s)^n}$, which is the same as $\frac {\varphi(a)} {\varphi(s)^n}$ in $B_{p_x}$. 

Res is just an embedding homomorphism! Bingo.